# I want the snow golem to do some damage to mobs, how can I set that on my server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-commands

I want to use the snow golems to create some kind of "smart turret", but I want them to do damage when shooting.
I don't want to use mods, I'd prefer a built-in solution if possible.

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin/code or a commandblock system?

Comment: Dragnoz explains how to kill with a snow ball [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dCldR5bpOo). A modification of the command should damage instead of kill.

Comment: I prefer a command, but if it cant not be done by command or changing a config file... then I can try mods.